# Multiplt session in win 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, rdp, console

as far i know the rdp session is 2 session maximum in win 2003, is there any way i can connect 3 remote session concurrently ?

also i tried many times to connect using the console mode, but it seem like i have only 2 session 1 console and 1 using the regular terminal services rdp session ?

Answer (score 1):

> i tried many times to connect using
>   the console mode, but it seem like i
>   have only 2 session 1 console and 1
>   using the regular terminal services
>   rdp session

That just means you're not connecting to the console properly.

Try either `mstsc /admin /v:machinename` or `mstsc /console /v:machinename`. Depending on your RDP version, one of those will work.

However, if you really need more sessions then you may want to add the [Terminal Services](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/terminalservices/default.mspx) role to the server. You'll need to sort out licensing though as I believe you'll need some TS licenses.

Comment: tried the command, but it didnt work, i am trying to connect from win xp sp3

Comment: which didn't work? With XP SP3 I'm pretty sure you'll need to use "mstsc /v:machinename /admin" (where you replace *machinename* with the real server name, of course)

Comment: i tried it chris, but it seem the same, mean if i have 2 ts session connected, i cant connect using console !

Any idea ?

Comment: I'm not sure, lyad. Are you getting an error of some sort? I've used this method with XP SP3 frequently. Relied on it quite a bit, to be honest!

Comment: yes i got the same error if you try to connect a 3rd one, maximum session !

Answer (score 0):

start-->run-->mstsc /admin

This works for service pack 3 and up. If you're connecting with sp2 or earlier you'll need to run 'mstsc /console'.

Your other option would be to open Terminal Services Manager from another server (or create your own MMC Snap-in if you've installed adminpak.msi on your workstation) and connect to the machine name in question. You can boot inactive sessions from there as well.